# AngularJS - scope not refreshing when change route

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

At first sorry for subject name, I didn't knew how to call it. I was searching for an answer but found nothing helpful or didn't knew how to implement this in my little app. I'm learning AngularJS and i thought a "drink counter" will be good for beginning. So all my app is supose to do is when you click a drink icon it adds an item(type of drink and datetime when) and the problem is that it isn't refreshing the drink list when I change route to /#archive/ it only does when I refresh page, my code is:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',
            {
                controller: 'myController',
                templateUrl: 'Views/home.html'
            })
        .when('/archive',
            {
                controller: 'myController',
                templateUrl: 'Views/archive.html'
            })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});

myApp.factory('myFactory', function () {
    var saved = localStorage.getItem('myData');
    var drinks = (localStorage.getItem('myData') !== null) ? JSON.parse(saved) : [];

    localStorage.setItem('myData', JSON.stringify(drinks));

    var factory = {};
    factory.getDrinks = function () {
        return drinks;
    };

    return factory;
});

var controllers = {};
controllers.myController = function ($scope, myFactory, $filter) {
    $scope.drinks = [];

    init();

    function init() {

        $scope.drinks = myFactory.getDrinks();

        $scope.beerDrinked = $filter('filter')($scope.drinks, 'beer').length;
    }

    $scope.nowDrinking = function (what) {
        $scope.drinks.push({
            drinkDate: new Date(),
            what: what
        });

        localStorage.setItem('myData', JSON.stringify($scope.drinks));
    };
}
myApp.controller(controllers);
```

Yes, sure. This is my HTML in archive:

```
<ul class="drinked" data-ng-repeat="drink in drinks | orderBy: 'drinkDate':true track by $index">
    <li class="{{ drink.what }}"><span class="date">{{ drink.drinkDate | date: 'EEEE, d MMMM yyyy' }}</span><span class="time">{{ drink.drinkDate | date: 'HH:mm:ss'}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

And this is in home:

```
<span data-ng-bind="beerDrinked"></span>
<a href="#" class="btn-drink" data-ng-click="nowDrinkig('beer')">beer</a>
```

Comment: I noticed that it is refreshing, but is ignoring filter. I.e. when I hit BEER it adds an item, but to the end of object(it is on the end of the list). And when I refresh it orders it properly.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to refresh your html, you´ve to use ng-repeat, example:

```
<div class="drinks" data-ng-repeat="drink in drinks"></div>
```

I don´t know where the user have to click to refresh you page, but to do this you´ve to use data-ng-click directive, example:

```
<button data-ng-click="addDrink(someDrink)"></button>
```

So in your controller should be like this, example:

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.drinks = [];
   $scope.addDrink= function (drink) { //note that you don´t need(and don´t should) to pass your drink by parameter...
      $scope.drinks.push(drink);
   }
```

});

Comment: Thanks for reply but the problem is not that they are not adding, couse I have exact same method that you propsed, but the problem is that when I change View I have an old object which does not contain this last click and when I refresh everything seems to be ok.

Comment: ok, i understand and one tip you don´t need "init" function... You´re using ng-repeat? Can you put the html?

Comment: Yes, sure. This is my HTML in archive:

  
    
    <ul class="drinked" data-ng-repeat="drink in drinks | orderBy: 'drinkDate':true track by $index">
     <li class="{{ drink.what }}"><span class="date">{{ drink.drinkDate | date: 'EEEE, d MMMM yyyy' }}</span><span class="time">{{ drink.drinkDate | date: 'HH:mm:ss'}}</span></li>
    </ul>
    

And this is in home:

    
    <span data-ng-bind="beerDrinked"></span>
    <a href="#" class="btn-drink" data-ng-click="nowDrinkig('beer')">beer</a>

Comment: are you using some debug? like firebug? Because, maybe you´re getting some error that is avoiding your script to put your new drink inside the html...

Comment: Yes, but no errors. Anyway if I click BEER icon it adds +1 to counter next to the beer.

Answer (score 0):

here, put your ng-repeat inside your li element, like this:

```
<ul class="drinked">
    <li data-ng-repeat="drink in drinks | orderBy: 'drinkDate':true track by $index" class="{{ drink.what }}"><span class="date">{{ drink.drinkDate | date: 'EEEE, d MMMM yyyy' }}</span><span class="time">{{ drink.drinkDate | date: 'HH:mm:ss'}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

Try it!

Comment: No diffrence unfortunetly. Still when I hit F5 it reloades the object, but it's not the point.

Comment: are you using some debug? Where "localStorage" is coming from?

Comment: localStorage is html5 new feature. But I think the reason for this is that I have an old object. Probably I just need to force my $scope.drinks to reload, but I don't know how.